# How to pass list to the selectExpr method in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Question seems simple but can't find easy way to solve it.

I'm trying to dynamically create new columns in `selectExpr`, but it won't accept a list as an argument. What would be the best way to achieve it? (Multiple `withColumn` is not an option because of the [stackoverflowexception](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html)
input:

```
a | b
-------
1 | zzz
2 | xxx
```

tried something like this

```
sample_new_cols = {"s":"ran-s", 
                  "ts": "current_timestamp()",
                  }

 df = df.selectExpr('*',
            [
                f"{definition} as {name}"
                for name, definition in sample_new_cols.items()
            ]
        )
```

and the output of it would be

```
a | b | s   | ts 
------------|-----------
1 |zzz|ran-s|2021-12-01 08:10:21
2 |xxx|ran-s|2021-12-01 08:10:21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it :

- for string static column definitions, you need to quote the values (eg. `'ran-s'`)
- and in `selectExpr`, you need to use asterisk `*` before the array of columns

```py
sample_new_cols = {
    "s": "'ran-s'",
    "ts": "current_timestamp()",
}

df1 = df.selectExpr('*', *[
    f"{definition} as {name}"
    for name, definition in sample_new_cols.items()
])

df1.show()

#+---+---+-----+-----------------------+
#|a  |b  |s    |ts                     |
#+---+---+-----+-----------------------+
#|1  |zzz|ran-s|2021-12-01 14:23:14.779|
#|2  |xxx|ran-s|2021-12-01 14:23:14.779|
#+---+---+-----+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Ha, thanks @blackbishop. I sorted it out literally few minutes I posted and then completely forgot I asked here.